# Where can I find an implementation of javax.validation.*?

Tags: java, validation, jar, implementation

I've just included a new library in my project and it's dependent on some classes in javax.validation - which I can't find an implementation of.  Is there a free implementation available that can be licensed for commercial, closed-source use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [Hibernate Validator 4](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html), it's an implementation of JSR 303 and uses javax.validation too.

Some examples:-

- http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2009/01/getting-started-with-jsr-303-beans.html

Comment: I downloaded hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar and included it in my build path, but my application still complains of the same missing class definition.  Pardon my ignorance, but how do I specify this jar file as an implementation of the necessary javax.validation classes?  I'm not using maven - just eclipse - and I don't understand the directions on the site to which you linked.  Sorry!

Comment: May I know what class defs are missing? You should be able to just drop it in and use it. What library are you using?

Comment: I'm missing (at least) `javax.validation.ValidationException`.  I'm using the JDK 1.6.0 that ships with Mac OS X, and google's appengine sdk (1.4).

Comment: Well, I downloaded `4.1.0.Final ` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/ and that missing class def is located in `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar`. Pull this jar into your build path and you will be all set.

Comment: Sorry, this turned out to be a gwt-specific problem, resolved by including gwt-servlet-deps.jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory.  See https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/a8c48b6ad09721c2  Thanks for your help limc